# Checkboxes not selectable and smaller in size

Tags: html, css, checkbox

for some reason my checkboxes will not work inside some divs.

They cant be checked and are around half the size they normally are...

They work in firefox, but not chrome and they dont even show in safari...

This is not a live site so cant give a link, but its just a basic checkbox code.

I have had a look around the css of the containing div etc but nothing seems out of place.

Any suggestions on what i could look for? Sorry if theres a lack of information.

Comment: "just a basic checkbox code" is not clear. You need to provide a sample of the markup along with relevant CSS and script. Use jsfiddle to reproduce the problem and include a link.

Comment: Are you using a reset stylesheet?

Comment: i have narrowed it down to me giving everything (*) a styling of 100% height and width. Need to re configure a few things but should be okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the computed style tab in the source view of chrome by pressing f12. You can then see all the styles that are applied to it and also add new styles. Experiment with it till you get the wanted result. Also, you can use [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.com) for posting bigger blocks of code.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks this helped me narrow down the source of the issue, used firebug instead but same difference :)